# QHelpEngine sorts contents (section) order, How to use default registration order?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt6

QHelpEngine seems to sort sections.

```
registerDocumentation(fileContentB)
registerDocumentation(fileContentC)
registerDocumentation(fileContentA)
```

will display

```
content A
content B
content C
```

But how to have default order, i.e:

```
content B
content C
content A
```